# What's the difference between 終わった and 終わっていた

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

> ① いつの間にかパーティーは終わっていた
>   ② いつの間にかパーティーは終わった

How do you interpret the two sentences above?

Answer (score 1):

This ～ている expresses "the continuation of state" as described in detail in [When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010)

- パーティーは終わっていた。 = The party had ended.
- パーティーは終わった。 = The party ended.

The former form is used when, for example, you visited somewhere but found there was already no one left. The latter is used when you just heard a closing address from the host.